# Howto disable password request on file creation on newly formatted hard disk

Tags: linux, unix, formatting, filesystems

I have just formatted an external hard disk using this command:

```
$ sudo mkfs -t ext3 /dev/sdc1
```

However, once this is done, whenever I want to create a directory
or file in this hard disk, it always ask for password (i.e. permission requirement).

Is there a way I can disable that?

Note that I can't format the partition with mkfs unless I use sudo.

Please advice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you mount the partition at /media/foo, then try this:

```
sudo chmod 1777 /media/foo
```

It'll act like /tmp does at that point. So any user can create a folder / file in there, but you can only delete your own files.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend you asking the same question at [ServerFault](http://serverfault.com). I think you'll get a better answer over there.

Comment: That would be a good idea for him to do if the link you gave wasn't to an (apparently) closed Beta.

Comment: It's not closed anymore. Anyone who types in alt.sysadmin.recovery can use Server Fault now, without needing 100 points on SO.

Comment: It's not really a closed beta anymore

Comment: @foolishbrat: look two lines up (or in the SO blog).